# Match Two Columns and Get Average From Third Column Displaying In Fourth Column

Tags: excel

Okay, this question is pretty complicated and may not be possible.

I have Zip codes in Column A (on average the same zip code is repeated 5 times in column A, with 2600 unique zip codes), I then have a number representing students in Column B (in some cases this number is sometimes 0), Then in Column C I have the unique Zip Codes Listed out.

I am trying to match Column A & C together and get an Average of Column B placed in Column D.

I tried: `=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0))` found in another answer, but this only get's me the first number that shows up in Column B and not the Average for those zip codes.

I have attached an Image of what it would look like (with me manually doing the math)

[image: Image of Ideal Solution Manually Entered]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you perhaps add a sample of data and expected result? Sometimes it's difficult to work off a description whereas a concrete example makes it much clearer. Edit your question and add it in there rather than using comments (because code-formatting in comments is awful). Also - we're not too fond of external links because they go stale, whereas Stack Overflow is forever :) Anything you can put into the actual question is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=AverageIf(A:A,C2,B:B)
```

This is a great formula that does basically exactly what you are trying to do.

[more info](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/averageif.php)

The formula was designed to do exactly what you are trying to do.  It performs Sumif/Countif.  This will scan Col A for all rows that match your cell C2.  Then it takes the average of all Col B values for those matched rows.

You could drag the formula down for all unique Zip Codes in column C.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much.